# findObjectInDocByType "argument number1 is invalid"

Tags: flash, jsfl

```
var objs = fl.findObjectInDocByType("instance", doc);
```

Error: findObjectInDocByType: Argument number1 is invalid.

Comment: I'm using Adobe Animate. Is this an API bug?

Comment: According to documentation "instance" is one of the valid arguments to provide: "shape", "text", "tlfText", "instance", "shapeObj". The problem is, while the very idea of JSFL as an AS-like script for automation tedious tasks about FLA projects, JSFL documentation (https://help.adobe.com/archive/en_US/flash/cs5/flash_cs5_extending.pdf) is pretty outdated, while the whole JSFL thing is undersupported. Over all the years I worked with Flash, there were 2 or 3 times when I **had** to resort to JSFL and each time I was out of it with the feeling of **please never again** rather than **oh cool**.